# MongoDB select last documents in 24 hours

Tags: mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using the MongoDB version 4.4, I'm trying to return the last documents inserted in the last 24 hous, and i need to run this query every day, because of this, i don't set the date manualy, I need to use new Date()

The problem is, when a put more arguments to bring me the last 24 hours, the MongoDB return a error message to me, and i try for many ways to resolve this, but nothing worked

This is my code

```js
{ 
    "$match" : { 
         "CreatedAt2" : { 
              "$gte" : ISODate("2022-04-21")
          }
     }
}
```

If i run this code, this works fine, but if a change the string by new Date(), the problem start.

In my test, if a put only new Date() like bellow and find by '$lte', the code rans good.

'$lte' is only to check if new Date() will works

```js
"CreatedAt2" :  {  $lte: new Date() }
```

So, if a tried to include the value to return the last 24 hours, my query don't work, look bellow

```js
"CreatedAt2" :  {  $gte: new Date(new Date().getTime() - 86400000) }
```

The MongoDB bring to me this error message

[image: error message]

Now I don't know what I need to do to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider leveraging the `$$NOW` aggregation variable and `$subtract` it by 24hours * 60minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds = 86400000 ms to get the records within 24 hours

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $gte: [
          "$CreatedAt2",
          {
            "$subtract": [
              "$$NOW",
              86400000
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ELjS86WRNHZ) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this code works to me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of subtracting 86400000 Milliseconds, you can also use

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $gte: [
          "$CreatedAt2",
          {
             $dateSubtract: {
                startDate: "$$NOW",
                unit: "hour",
                amount: 24
             }
           }     
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Or use a 3rd party date-library, e.g. [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

```
{ 
    "$match" : { 
         "CreatedAt2" : { 
              "$gte" : moment().subtract(24, 'hours').toDate()
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Just wondering whether $dateSubtract is available in MongoDB v4.4 yet...?

Comment: No, it was introduced in version 5.0

Comment: I think it might be a good idea to add back the versioning information. The answer is clean and nice but may not be applicable to OP's v4.4. However, I think this decent answer can be kept for reference. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"createdAt2":{$gte:new Date(Date.now() - 86400)
```

This should work fine